# помогите поправить код в соответствии с шаблонами проектирования

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Пытаюсь научиться применять шаблоны проектирования, но пока все очень плохо, написал небольшой кусочек кода - https://github.com/sergeevpasha/patterntest
Подскажите что поправить, где я не правильно рассуждал

Писать весь код тут - очень много, а писать частично - бессмысленно. Не удаляйте плиз сообщение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос очень дискуссионный. Далее напишу сугубо личное мнение, не претендующее на полноту и правильность

**MailMessenger.php**

```
\Mail::send($email);
```

Это не всегда очень хорошо т.к. появляется неявная зависимость. Лучше заменять на явную зависимость `$mail->send($email);`, которую подключать через конструктор класса.

**EmailTemplateFactory.php**

```
public function getTemplate(...
```

Слишком много аргументов у метода. Лучше заменить на fluent интерфейс

```
switch ($emailableType) {
```

В данном случае всю эту конструкцию нужно заменить на что-то более автоматизированное. При появлении новых классов вам придётся переписывать этот файл. Что не есть хорошо.

```
case 'App\Models\Order':
```

Строковые значения имён классов лучше заменять на `\App\Models\Order::class`. В случае внезапного рефакторинга поможет избежать ненужных ошибок

**OrderEmailTemplate.php**

```
public function __construct(...
```

Слишком много аргументов в конструкторе. Лучше заменить на fluent интерфейс

Comment: с fluent разобрался, но куда деть switch логику? я хочу чтобы на основе emailable_type выбиралось какой шаблон должен исполняться

Comment: в самом классе, который у вас указан в `case` можно в статический метод или статическую переменную записать имя класса шаблона. Но тогда нужно будет унифицировать передачу аргументов. Есть ещё вариант, с выносом связи класса и шаблона в конфигурационный файл. В таком случае нужно будет делать фабрику (фабрики).